# Change VBA Font, not Excel's Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro in VBA, but I can't seem to change the details of the editor font of the text that I am typing in VBA.

By this I mean, I don't care what color the font is in Excel, but I want to be able to more clearly see the blue lettering when I type in the VBA window.

I looked online, but I could only find websites to change the text of the Excel cells. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On VBA editor:

1. Click menu "Tools", and then click "Options..."
2. Click on the "Editor format" tab, and change whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

Go into the VBA window, go to tools. Then click options. Under the tab "Editor Format" changing the foreground color to whatever you desire will change the color of the colored vba text. I believe that is what you are looking for.